# Unable to run python package stand-alone and nested under another repoistory

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, git-submodules

I created a python package which I use for brain preprocessing - named `bpt`. I would also like to use the same package as a sub-module in another project named `brain_seg`.
As a results, I am having problems with import statements which either results in errors when running the package stand-alone or nested.

The structure of the `bpt` package is as follows:

```
bpt
   |--__init__.py
   |--module1.py
   |--module2.py
   |--run.py
```

Import statements in the file `run.py` look something like:

```
import os
import module1
import module2

.
.
.
```

The structure of the `brain_seg` package is as follows:

```
brain_seg
   |--bpt
   |     |--__init__.py
   |     |--module1.py
   |     |--module2.py
   |     |--run.py
   |
   |--package2
   |     |--__init__.py
   |     |--module1a.py
   |
   |--__init__.py
```

When running the `run.py` script which is part of the stand alone `bpt` package, everything runs as expected.

If I try to run the same script as part of the `brain_seg` package, the following error is dispatched:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'
```

I tried to use relative imports so the nested project will work as expected, resulting in the following `run.py` file:

```
import os
from . import module1
from . import module2

.
.
.
```

Following the change, execution of the `brain_seg` project worked as expected but when I tried to call the `run.py` script from the stand alone `bpt` package, it resulted in the following error being dispatched:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How should I handle the imports such that both options will be supported?

Comment: I assume you're running the script from the `run.py` file. Unless the `bpt` package is installed in your `bpt`, you should probably be running the script from a file *outside* of `bpt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports in `bpt.run` must be absolute or relative:

```
from bpt.module1 import ... # absolute
from .module1 import ...  # relative
```

To run `bpt.run` from your repository root with your pythonpath getting correctly set, use `-m`:

```
python bpt/run.py  # bad
python -m bpt.run  # good
```

If `brain_seg` is not truly meant to be a package itself, but just a project consisting of multiple packages and modules, get rid of `brain_seg/__init__.py`.

If you do mean to use it as a package, then move it below the repo root, i.e.

```
- README.md (etc.)
- .gitignore (etc.)
- brain_seg
  - __init__.py
  - bps
    - __init__.py
    - main.py
```

and use e.g. `python -m brain_seg.bps.run`
from the repository root.

If you also intend to use `bps` as a standalone thing, I wouldn't recommend keeping it in the `brain_seg` hierarchy at all, but to make it `pip install`able (see https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and then `pip install -e ../somewhere/bps` to have pip set up an editable link between your projects.